# Image style effect for removing empty space around image

Tags: 7, media

There can be a lot of situations when e. g. set of logos in png format are not cropped regularly and some images can have different white spaces around the actual logo in the image.

Is there any module that adds an image style effect capable of cropping white space (transparent or white) around image?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can with a module. The only solution is use Photoshop or else.
[ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) is the best module for custom style image, but I don't believe is going to...